# Why do I need Amazon S3 and Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I've read a lot of articles stating that I should be using Amazon S3 in conjunction with the CDN Cloudfront.  I'm currently not doing this.  I'm simply using Cloudfront with my standard shared hosting package.

Is it OK to use Cloudfront on its own with my standard shared hosting package?  Surely there is no added benefit to using S3 also as the files are already located within Cloudfront.

Any enlightenment on this is much appreciated.

Leigh

Answer (score 1):

S3 allows you to do things like static webhosting, with logging and redirection. I.E www.example.com redirects to example.com. You can then use Cloudfront to place your assets as close to the end user as possible ("nearest edge location"). An excellent guide on how to do this is in the AWS docs. Two main things are that S3 supports https, and changes to files in S3 are reflected instantly. Because Cloudfront is a CDN, you have to manually expire files if you change them, otherwise is could take up to 24 hours to reflect your changes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html

A quick comparison between the two is given here:
http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/cloudfront--amazon-s3-vs-amazon-cloudfront.html

Comment: Also, depending on the size of your usage, I think cloudfront might be more expensive (as it has to replicate your storage in multiple locations). You could look at http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html if that is a concern.

Comment: This (CF costlier that S3) should now happen even rarely as data transfer from S3 to CloudFront is free since Dec, 2014 (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2780)

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem of using CloudFront against your own origin server comparing to a S3 server.

There are some benefits of using S3:

- Data transfer is faster between S3 and CloudFront
- Don't need to worry about the stability and maintenance of origin S3 server
- Multiple origin regions

There are also benefits if you use your own server:

- Cost saving of S3 hosting (this depends on whether you need to pay for your own server)
- Easy for customization should you need it
- Data storage location for company/country regulation

So it's all depending on your specific circumstances, such as how much you pay for your hosting package, do you need low-level configuration of your origin server, and how sensitivity your data is.

I would say for majority of the small/medium projects, S3 is a perfect place to store data.